# How to disable Special Characters and Number in textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox

For example in my form I will need to input my name in a textbox but when there's a special character or number in a textbox or a number, a messagebox will pop up saying that "Please type a valid name" after pressing the button.

[image]

Comment: Depends on how you define "special character".

Comment: all characters that are not A-Z, a-z and Space

Comment: What if my name is Renée Nyström? Or 田中太郎?

Comment: Wow I didn't think about that but I will make a local application where the peoples name are Alphabetical.

Comment: Your local area has zero foreign people living there...?

Comment: It's a loosing game to tell people how they can write their names. How about Tim Berners-Lee? You might reasonably restrict Cc, Cf, Zi, Zp [categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#CategoryOrBlock). Anything else has what purpose? [At least you aren't telling people that they have to have a first and a last name. But, do keep in mind many, say half, have no name for at least a day during their lives.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid it doing wrong recognition when someone enters a non-ASCII character but valid name (such as 田中太郎), you may need to really list down the special characters you don't want to include.

But to keep it simple, if what you mean by special characters are all other than white space and alphabet, then simply use built-in function `char.IsLetter` and `char.IsWhiteSpace`:

```
if (str.Any(c => !char.IsLetter(c) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))){
    //invalid
} else {
    //valid
}
```

If you want to check for some specific range of characters and not others given the above checking, simply put your additional checking in the `//invalid` part:

```
if (str.Any(c => !char.IsLetter(c) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))){
    //possible invalid
    if (some additional character range checking){
        //valid case
    } else {
        //truly invalid
        //add as many else if as you want
    }
} else {
    //valid
}
```

Comment: How do i use this? for example my txtbox name is FN?

Comment: and it says ) expected

Comment: @leimelson06 it should be triple closing parenthesis `)))` instead of two `))` now it should be OK. Get the `str` from your `TextBox.Text`, for example: `string str = textBoxFullName.Text;` or `string str = FN.Text` then you can apply the above checking.

Comment: Thank you. You really helped me.

Comment: @leimelson06 no problem! glad that I can be of any help. :)